# Mac "cmd" + "." key not working US keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard

In whichever application I try, or on a website (https://keyboardchecker.com/), I cannot get <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> key working on my US keyboard.

I have used this combination for years now as a shortcut to "format document" in VSCode. Yet, ever since a while ago it ceased to work. I have no idea why or how as both keys work separately and I have not changed any system files. I tested on multiple keyboards.

Env.:

```
MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021)
Apple M1 Pro
Monterey v 12.5.1 (21G83)
```

Comment: I don't know if this relates, but that key chord has been used as a shortcut for hitting "cancel" or "escape" since the very earliest days of the Macintosh because the original Mac's keyboard was very compact and didn't have an escape key. As a longtime Mac user, I never would have thought it was available to be redefined. It's as ancient as the shortcuts for cut and paste. Anyway, did you look through the system keyboard shortcuts to see if it's been defined to mean something else? Maybe something in the OS is swallowing that keystroke and not letting VSCode see it?

Comment: The combination is not listed on https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236 .
I also checked with cheatsheet if its in my local system, but it is not.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/71347942 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/380250/85275 As Spiff says, this has been in use since Apple wore short pants ;)